# Add microphone audio recording entry to ASP.NET Core MVC Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When a user is filling out an ASP.NET Core MVC form, how can I have an entry that is a microphone audio recording (where the user can record right there on the page)? I tried

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Dictation</label>
       <input type="file" name="audio" accept="audio/*" capture="microphone">
</div>
```

But all that does is give me a FormFile-style 'Choose File' box to select an audio file from the computer.

What's the best, cross-platform, standardized way to do this without having to bring in any gigantic javascript libraries?

Comment: Not sure that there is a 100%-foolproof way of capturing audio. Does this help? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio

Comment: Do you want to capture some audio from the browser, or just upload a pre-recorded .mp3?

Comment: capture audio from the browser. I updated my question to make that more clear. Thanks!